# how to write php code inside sql query?

Tags: php, sql

the code is like this

```
$sql="SELECT tahun FROM tahunajar ";
```

i want the value of $sql can write in this query

```
$sql1= "SELECT * FROM soal where idSoal LIKE '-->HERE<--' ";
```

can someone tell me how do it?

Comment: That makes no sence.

Comment: try this: `$sql1= "SELECT * FROM soal where idSoal LIKE '$sql' "; `

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse, you can write it via like this

```
$sql1= "SELECT * FROM soal where idSoal IN (".$sql.") ";
```

Comment: i have tried `<?php
include 'admin/connect.php';
$sql="SELECT tahun FROM tahunajar; ";
$sql1= "SELECT * FROM soal where idSoal LIKE (".$sql."%) "; 
$result = mysql_query($sql1, $koneksi);
?>`  but i get error "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in..line 23", the code on line 23 is while($soal=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ...}..can you help me for this error?

Comment: Try to remove this (".$sql."%) to "$sql%"

Comment: Rather than LIKE, you should use `IN` clause because your inner query may return multiple values

Comment: What's the query if I want to combine the LIKE value "$sql, 5,%" ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the variable in double quoted string. It will work. Following is the example:

```
$sql1= "SELECT * FROM soal where idSoal LIKE $sql";
```

You can learn more from [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Comment: What's the query if I want to combine the LIKE value "$sql, 5,%" ?